# Asymptotic behavior of a certain oscillatory integral

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

Let $x>0$ and consider the integral
$$I(x):=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{i r}}{r^{\frac{1}{2}}} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{r}{sx+\sqrt{sxr}+r} \, ds \, dr.$$

I am trying to determine the asymptotic behavior of $I(x)$ as $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}I(x)=0$.
Here is why:

---

Notice that
$(r,s)\mapsto{e^{i r}}{r^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{-s}}{s^{-\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{r^{2}}{s^2 x^2+sxr+r^2}$
is dominated by ${r^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^{-s}}{s^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$ which is an $L^{1}([0,1]\times [0,+\infty[)$ function.

On $[1,+\infty[\times [0,+\infty[$ we need an integration by parts w.r.t. $r$ to justify the passing of the limit as $x\rightarrow+\infty$. Doing so, we get
\begin{align}
& \int_1^\infty\frac{e^{i r}}{r^{\frac{1}{2}}} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{r}{sx+\sqrt{sxr}+r} \, ds \, dr \\[6pt]
= {} & {i e^{i }}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{1}{sx+\sqrt{sx}+1} \, ds \\[6pt]
& {}+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{i r}}{r^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{r}{sx+\sqrt{sxr}+r} \, ds \, dr \\[6pt]
& {}-\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{i r}}{r^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}} \left(\frac{r}{sx+\sqrt{sxr}+r} -\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{sxr}+r}{(sx+\sqrt{sxr}+r)^2} \right)\, ds \, dr \tag{$**$}
\end{align}

Simple remarks on the formula $(**)$:

(1) The limit (taken at computing the boundary terms) and derivative under the $s$-integral are both justified by
the fact that $e^{-s}/\sqrt{s}\in L^1 ([0,+\infty[)$.

(2) A factor $1/r$ has been pulled outside the $s$-integral.

More importantly,

(3) The integrand in this formula, as a function of $(r,s)$, is absolutely dominated by
$r^{-3/2}s^{-1/2}e^{-s}$ which is an $L^1( \left[1,+\infty\right[\times [0,+\infty[ )$ function.

---

What is the precise asymptotic behavior of $I(x)$ as $x\to+\infty\text{ ?}$

I am probably  wrong, but I tried  rescaling/changing order of integration/Taylor-expanding the rational factor in any variable. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can evaluate $I(x)$ explicitly, and then asymptotically.

Indeed, using the substitution $s=ru/x$, we get
\begin{equation*}
    I(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}\lim_{R\to\infty}J_R(x), \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    J_R(x)&:=\int_0^R dr\,e^{ir}\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{\sqrt u\,(u+\sqrt u+1)}e^{-ru/x} \\ 
    &=\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{\sqrt u\,(u+\sqrt u+1)}\int_0^R dr\,e^{(i-u/x)r} \\ 
    &=\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{\sqrt u\,(u+\sqrt u+1)}\frac{1-e^{(i-u/x)R}}{u/x-i}.  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Next, (i) for any real $u,x>0$ we have $\dfrac{1-e^{(i-u/x)R}}{u/x-i}\to\dfrac1{u/x-i}$ as $R\to\infty$, (ii) for any real $u,x,R>0$ we have $\Big|\dfrac{1-e^{(i-u/x)R}}{u/x-i}\Big|\le\dfrac2{|u/x-i|}\le2$, and (iii) for any real $x>0$ we have $\displaystyle{\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{\sqrt u\,(u+\sqrt u+1)}\,2<\infty}$.

So, by dominated convergence,
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{R\to\infty}J_R(x)=J(x), \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &J(x):=\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{\sqrt u\,(u+\sqrt u+1)}\frac1{u/x-i} \\   
    &=\frac{x \left(-18 \ln x+\pi  \left(8 i \sqrt{3} x+(9-9 i) \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x}-\frac{18
   \sqrt[4]{-1}}{\sqrt{x}}+4 \sqrt{3}+9 i\right)\right)}{18 (-1+x (x-i))}  
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
(note that the integrand in \eqref{3} is rational in $\sqrt u\,$, so that one can use partial fraction decomposition to get \eqref{3}).
So, as $x\to\infty$,
\begin{equation*}
    J(x)\to c:=\frac{4 i \pi }{3 \sqrt{3}},
\end{equation*}
so that, by \eqref{1},
\begin{equation*}
    I(x)\sim \frac c{\sqrt x}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: You could have stopped at the first equality in (3) and taken the limit as $x\to+\infty$. Basically, instead of regularizing with a Gaussian $e^{-\epsilon r}$ you regularized with a characteristic function $\chi_{[0,R]}(r)$. Equation (1) needs justification, but I know how to do it. To me both answers are correct. But, I will accept yours because the computations are slightly simpler. Thank you prof. Pinelis.

Comment: @Medo : You are welcome. I appreciate your acceptance. However, I have something to say concerning your comments. (i) Indeed, the first equality in (3) is enough for the first-order asymptotic. However, it costs almost nothing to get the explicit expression for $J(x)$, which can then be used e.g. to get asymptotics of any orders. (ii) Your double integral $I(x)$ cannot be understood in the Lebesgue sense. So, it must be defined somehow. Formula (1) provides such a definition, arguably the most conventional one; so, being a definition, (1) needs no justification.

Comment: Previous comment continued: (iii) As I see it, the main difference between the two answers is that my answer is complete and completely rigorous, with nothing neglected. To appreciate the difference, you can try to go along the lines of the other answer and fill the gaps delineated in my comments on that answer.

Answer (score 12):

$$I(x):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i r}}{r^{\frac{1}{2}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{r}{sx+\sqrt{sxr}+r}ds dr.$$
To aid the asymptotic analysis, I regularize $I(x)$ by multiplying the integrand with $e^{-\epsilon r}$, sending $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$ at the end. I also change variables from $sx\mapsto s$,
$$I_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int _0^{\infty }dr\int _0^{\infty }ds\,\frac{\sqrt{r}  \exp \left(i r-\epsilon r-s/x\right)}{\sqrt{s} \left(\sqrt{r s}+r+s\right)}.$$
For large $x$ I may neglect the term $-s/x$ in the exponent.$^\ast$ The integrals over $s$ and $r$ can then be evaluated in closed form,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}I_\epsilon(x)=\frac{4 \pi i }{3 \sqrt{3x}}+{\cal O}(1/x).$$
This matches a numerical check.

---

$^\ast$
The order $1/x$ error incurred by replacing $e^{-s/x}$ by 1 follows from the expansion
$x^{-1/2}\int_1^\infty s^{-3/2}e^{-s/x}\,ds=2x^{-1/2}-2\sqrt{\pi}x^{-1}+2x^{-3/2}+\cdots.$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you give a hint on how you got the remainder $O(1/x)$ ? Thanks again.

Comment: (i) "For large $x$ I may neglect the term $-s/x$ in the exponent." -- Neglect in what mathematical sense, and why? Even for large $x$, $s/x$ may be large for large enough $s$. (ii) Did you mean to claim that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}I_\epsilon(x)=I(x)$? If so, why is it true? If not, then I don't see a proof here.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker. Yes, clear. But what about the piece $\int_0^1 e^{-s/x} /\sqrt{s}ds$ ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : "large-$x$ approximation is justified". -- Again, in what sense? Also, such a justification should be/should have been provided. But even then, that would only be a justification for $\sim I_\epsilon(x)$ as $x\to\infty$, whereas you need a justification for $\sim I(x)$ as $x\to\infty$, and your 
$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}I_\epsilon(x)$ for a "fixed* $x$ is not enough for that.